# Create new category instance inside template - prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I know i can use category class methods inside `.tpl` template files like this:

```
{assign var='all_categories' value=Category::getCategories()}
```

But how can i actually initialize Category object inside template? So that `__construct` function runs.

I ask this because when i try to use some Category class functions, i get this error:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to instance a category through a tpl file, some classes have a public static method to do this, eg, like the `Db` class, this have one called `getInstance`, unfortunately by default doesn't exist nothing similar in the `Category` class. You should instance it in a php file and send to Smarty, or modify the class adding an object:

`public static $instance = array();`

And the method:

```
public static function getInstance($id_category)
{
    if (isset(self::$instance[$id_category])) {
        return self::$instance[$id_category];
    }

    return self::$instance[$id_category] = new Category($id_category);
}
```

Now you can use in your tpl:

`{assign var='category' value=Category::getInstance(3)}`